# Rename all txt files in a folder based on file content

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Can someone please help to use `PowerShell` to rename individual `txt` files in a folder, each file needs to be renamed based on a keyword inside each individual `txt` file.

e.g.

`c:\temp\1.txt` may have a line like **Invoice#: 4422** so it needs to be renamed as `4422.txt`

`c:\temp\2.txt` may have a line like **Invoice#: 5454** so it needs to be renamed as `5454.txt`

and so on..

I am able to get the invoice number by Regex as

```
$filecontents -match "INVOICE\#: (\d+):"
```

The **C:\temp** folder contains a big number of `txt` files with different invoice numbers and PS script needs to rename all files.
Thanks,

Comment: The invoice number will **always** be a 4 digit number?

Comment: Invoice# could be 4 to 9 digits, however, in the above regex the (\d+): is able to get the entire invoice number regardless of its lenght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if it works remove the `-WhatIf` switch on `Rename-Item`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\*.txt"
$index = [collections.generic.list[string]]::new()

foreach($file in $files)
{
    if((Get-Content $file -Raw) -match '(?<=Invoice#:\s)\d+')
    {
        $invoiceNumber = $matches[0]
        
        if($index.contains($invoiceNumber))
        {
            Write-Warning "File with name $invoiceNumber.txt already exists. Skipping."
            continue
        }

        "Renaming {0} to $invoiceNumber.txt" -f $file.Name
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName $invoiceNumber.txt -WhatIf
        $index.Add($invoiceNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :) @M-ACharlotte

Comment: @M-ACharlotte I actually made a mistake handling possible files with the same name, the code is updated.